# É possível criar um "sinônimo" de uma função, dois nomes para mesma função?

Tags: php

Eu possuo um conjunto de funções usando uma API de terceiros. De um tempo para cá pensei em disponibilizá-la, uma vez que não existe nenhuma biblioteca publica em PHP e não faz diferença manter como um código fechado ou não. (*Ainda terei que modificar muita coisa.*)

Porém, como apenas eu utilizo tais funções, elas possuem nomes estranhos e que não condiz com o real resultado, além de não ter nenhum prefixo. Para resolver isso pensei em simplesmente renomear as funções e incluir um prefixo.

Dessa forma todas as funções mudariam para:

```
MinhaApi_*
```

Porém, isso ficaria muito longo para escrever, logo pensei em encurtar para:

```
ma_*
```

Daí surgiu a curiosidade:

**É possível ter `MinhaApi_*` e `ma_*` simultaneamente, sem declará-las duas vezes?**

Para que consiga entender, ao invés de usar isso:

```
function MinhaApi_text(){
   return 'Isso é um texto';
}

function ma_text(){
   return MinhaApi_text();
}

echo ma_text();
```

```
Resultado: Isso é um texto
```

> Isso funciona, porém exige que "re-declare" todas as funções (por isso acredito que não seja a melhor maneira).

Usar isso:

```
function MinhaApi_text(), ma_text(){
      return 'Isso é um texto';
}

echo ma_text();
```

```
Resultado "esperado": Isso é um texto
```

> Isso **não** funciona, logicamente!

Comment: Se entendi direito dá sim p dar um alias p função, entratando vc precisa usar namespaces e na chamada( `use`) dar o nome desejado.

Comment: @rray, para funções também dá? pensei que era só para `classes`

Comment: Da sim, agora se é prático no seu caso, não sei. Tirado da documentação: "PHP Namespaces provide a way in which to group related classes, interfaces, functions and constants"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A partir do PHP 5.6 existe um novo recurso para criar um alias

http://docs.php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.use

Exemplo:

```
use function minhaapi as ma;
```

Para versões anteriores, não há muito o que fazer. Normalmente usa-se lambda functions ou gambiarras com variáveis variáveis.

Comment: Não sabia desse recurso, realmente funcionou.

Comment: Realmente muito bom! Não tinha encontrado isso na minha pesquisa. Pena que só vai servir para a versão 5.6, que está ausente da maioria dos servidores de hospedagem atualmente.

Answer (score 1):

Pesquisei bastante e não encontrei alternativa. A forma como você está fazendo é elegante e também a uso muito. Eu costumo usá-la para fazer nomes de funções intuitivos, para que o programador não fique com dúvidas na ordem do nome da função, por exemplo:

```
<?php

function string_convert($var) {
// do something
}

function convert_string($var) {
    return string_convert($var);
}

<?
```

Se você tiver um arquivo PHP com todas as funções (muitas para valer a pena) já padronizadas com funções nomeadas como `MinhaApi_<algumacoisa>`, você poderá criar um script PHP que abrirá tal arquivo, criará e gravará em um novo arquivo PHP as funções "irmãs" das que já existem, atribuindo o novo nome e retornando a função original. Caso contrário, recomendo fazer manualmente, como você mesmo fez no primeiro exemplo.